# Is there any top document for ATC glossary?

Tags: air-traffic-control, phraseology

I have been searching for some official documents that have all ATC phrases, because I wanted to refresh some of the phrases for ATC, but I was not able to find any other than:

- Eurocontrol Phraseology database (https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/phraseology/Default.aspx)
- FAA pilot controller glossary (https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/pcg_change_1_dtd_12-2-21.pdf)
- Glossary from the faculty of transportation sciences CTU Prague (https://aim.rlp.cz/predpisy/predpisy/dokumenty/L/L-Frazeologie/data/effective/cast_II.pdf)

Is there any **official** document produced by any international organisation (for example ICAO) that almost every country respects or do my search results have everything needed for standart ATC communication?

Comment: Add this for your US list: https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/1029467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> International standards of phraseology are laid down in ICAO Annex 10 Volume II Chapter 5, ICAO Doc 4444 Chapter 12 and in ICAO Doc 9432 - Manual of Radiotelephony and in  Amendment 4 to the Acceptable Means of Compliance and Guidance Material to Regulation (EU) No 923/2012. Many national authorities also publish radiotelephony manuals which amplify ICAO provisions, and in some cases modify them to suit local conditions.

[Source](https://skybrary.aero/articles/standard-phraseology)